how to append large data set to a netcdf file - python
I have a 10,000 x 10,000 data set that I would like to store in a dataset format. I was looking into HDF5, but I found myself looking into Xarray for data storage. I do not have a beefy computer and, as such, cannot fully load the entire dataset into memory to perform a single conversion. Previously, I was reading line by line to import data, but from other questions about xarray, it appears this is not possible with netcdf and xarray.
I chose to use a format where I would save each row as a new group, but I feel like this is not the best for data storage.
the data structure for the table is as follows.
    a           b            c             d          e   . . .
a   1           0.2134523    0.3215321     0.874      -0.003
b   0.2134523   1           -0.213453      0.08080    0.8675309
c   0.3215321   -0.213453    1             0.314135   -0.4111
d   0.874       0.08080      0.314135      1          0.00003
e   -0.003      0.8675309    -0.4111       0.00003    1
.
.
.

structurally, the data is the same down the diagonal as this is comparison data between the two groups. I could technically cut it in half and still maintain all the data. I thought about doing this but reading up on how xarray works made me decide against it.
The code I am using is below.
label_data = pd.read_excel('./my10000_label.xlsx')
file_local_path = Path("./my10000_data.txt")
hf = h5py.File("./savedata.h5")


local_idx = 0
with file_local_path.open() as my_data:
    while True:
        line = my_data.readline()
        if not line:
            break

        line_array = np.fromstring(line, dtype=np.float64, sep=",")
        label = label_data.loc[local_idx]

        xdata = xarray.DataArray(line_array, dims=["lbl"], coords={"lbl":label_data["label"]})
        hf.create_dataset(label, data=xdata)
        local_idx += 1

hf.close()       

Is there a better method to save float data in a compressed array format? I have read that data can be loaded pieces of data using numpy.memmap but it doesn't look like I can go the other way and save data in a similar manner.

That's not the right way.  Is your input file just a CSV with floating point values?  numpy should be able to import that directly, without going one item at a time.

yes it is just a csv with floating point values. but I only have 2 gb of memory for processing and the 10,000 x 10,000 array eats up the memory quickly if I do not go line by line

depends on what you want to do with this. parquet could be a good option.

ideally, I will be opening the file and grabbing a slice. I will not need to open up the entire array.
